# Javascript - Assigning variables based off condition in for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement

I am using a for loop to assign my Highcharts data certain variables under a condition.

One of these variables I would like to assign is `linkedTo= ":previous"` IF `graphData.Title` appears more then once. I am having problems executing this logic in my existing for loop.

For example, on the first `graphData.Title === "LOW"` I would like linkedTo to not exist. If the array has `graphData.Title === "LOW"` more then once assign the variable `linkedTo= ":previous"`

The way I am currently handling this is creating a condition on `LOW` and then having another condition if graphTitle is `LOW` and greater then 1 assign it the linkedTo variable.

I expect this same outcome for every other possible condition on the title.

```
for (let i = 0; i < graphData.length; i++) {
        let graphColor = "#000000";
        let graphIndex = 0
        let linkedTo = ""

        if (graphData[i].title === "LOW") {
            graphColor = "#0D6302";
            graphIndex = 4;
        } else if (graphData[i].Title === "LOW" && graphData[i].Title === "LOW" > 1) { 
            graphColor = "#0D6302";
            graphIndex = 4;
            linkedTo = ":previous"
        } else if (graphData[i].title === "MEDIUM-LOW") {
            graphColor = "#0B7070";
            graphIndex = 3;
        } else if (graphData[i].title === "MEDIUM") {
            graphColor = "#DC9603";
            graphIndex = 2;
        } else if (graphData[i].title === "MEDIUM-HIGH") {
            graphColor = "#DD5F0C";
            graphIndex = 1;
        } else if (graphData[i].title === "HIGH") {
            graphColor = "#C50710";
            graphIndex = 0;
        }
```

Comment: What is this supposed to check: `(graphData[i].Title === "LOW" && graphData[i].Title === "LOW" > 1)` ..?

Comment: This is my attempt at the logic I described up top. If title equals Low and is greater then one (if its the second, third, forth title low) assign it the variable

Comment: @Teemu is there any examples you can provide?

Comment: We don't have your data, but take a look at [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/5ypesL4o/1/).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with the code, mainly that you're comparing a boolean true to be greater than one (not possible), and a lesser check comes before a more strict check (meaning the latter will never be evaluated). Also, titles aren't being collected, so the check itself is a bit absurd.

```
if (graphData[i].title === "LOW") {     // <<< Less strict, blocks the next check
    graphColor = "#0D6302";
    graphIndex = 4;                     // The below is true > 1 
} else if (graphData[i].Title === "LOW" && graphData[i].Title === "LOW" > 1) {
```

Here is an alternate approach, giving a settings object and collecting titles to check the count of the titles previously seen. I don't know quite the logic of how `graphColor`, `graphIndex` and `linkedTo` variables were being used, so YMMV.

```
const titleSeen = title => titles.filter(titleSeen => titleSeen === title).length > 1

let settings = {
    LOW: { color: '#0D6302', index: 4, linkedTo: null },
    'MEDIUM-LOW': { color: '#0B7070', index: 3, linkedTo: null },
    MEDIUM: { color: '#DC9603', index: 2, linkedTo: null },
    'MEDIUM-HIGH': { color: '#DD5F0C', index: 1, linkedTo: null },
    HIGH: { color: '#C50710', index: 0, linkedTo: null }
}
let titles = []

for (let i = 0; i < graphData.length; i++) {
    let setting = { color: '#000000', index: 0, linkedTo: null }
    let currentTitle = graphData[i].title

    titles.push(currentTitle)

    if (settings.hasOwnProperty(currentTitle)) {
        setting = settings[currentTitle]

        if (titleSeen(currentTitle)) {
            setting.linkedTo = ':previous'
        }
    }

    // setting would need to be used here somehow, due to the loop
}
```